# In exponential growth, what does it mean for the derivative to be proportional to the quantity iself?

Tags: calculus

I'm largely curious as to what that specifically means: the equation usually associated with this would be like $y(x) = y(0) * e^{kt}$, but I don't see the proportionality of its derivative to itself. I've tried calculating between different $e$-exponential charts but I have a hard time seeing what it means by proportional. If somebody could point it out, that'd be sweet.

Comment: The derivative is proportional to the value. The proportionality constant is $k$.

Comment: I assume that by "quantity" they mean some differentiable function $f(x)$. Then proportional means $f'(x)/f(x)=k$ for some constant $k$. Which can be satisfied only if $f(x)$ is of the form $Ce^{kx}$, i.e. when $f$ is exponential.

Comment: Thanks for the help, peeps! The answer + the comments helped me connect the dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean something like

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = ky(x),
\end{equation}

where the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ is proportional to $y$ itself (which here is a function of $x$). Your question is then (I think) why are exponential functions described in this way?

If so, the answer is because the equation above is the differential equation for an exponential function. To see this, we can solve it using the separation of variables method. First, we move the $y$ over to the other side of the equation.

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} = k
\end{equation}

Then we integrate both sides with respect to $x$.

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int k dx
\end{equation}

On the left-hand-side we 'separate' the variables, putting $(dy/dx)dx = dy$, so the integration is now over $y$. Meanwhile, on the right-hand-side, the integration is straight-forward.

\begin{equation}
\int\frac{dy}{y} = kx + C.
\end{equation}

Here, $C$ is the constant of integration.

The integral on the left just evaluates to the natural logarithm (here we assume that any constant of integration can be absorbed into the $C$ on the right-hand-side).

\begin{equation}
\log_{e}(y) = kx + C.
\end{equation}

Taking the anti-log on both sides gives

\begin{equation}
y(x) = e^{kx + C} = Ae^{kx},
\end{equation}

where we have put $A=e^{C}$. When $x=0$, we have

\begin{equation}
y(0) = A
\end{equation}

So we have our final result

\begin{equation}
y(x) = y(0)e^{kx}
\end{equation}

As you can see, this is an exponential function.